# unable to change the value of a property

Tags: c#, properties

I am currently improving my program that [I posted on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193676/another-attempt-at-a-blackjack-game) but I ran into a problem. I have a property called `Total` but when I try to set it to a value (0) it remains the same.

This is the property:

```
public class Player
{
    private int total;
    public int Total
    {
        get
        {
            total = 0;
            foreach (int card in hand)
            {
                total += card;
            }
            return total;
        }
        set { this.total = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is how I try to change it:

```
public class Game
{
    private void CompareHands()
    {
        //This is just for testing
        Console.WriteLine($"player total: {player1.Total}, is bust: {player1.Bust}");
        Console.WriteLine($"house total: {house.Total}, is bust: {house.Bust}");

        if (player1.Bust)
            player1.Total = 0;
        if (house.Bust)
            house.Total = 0;

        //this too
        Console.WriteLine($"player total: {player1.Total}, is bust: {player1.Bust}");
        Console.WriteLine($"house total: {house.Total}, is bust: {house.Bust}");
...
}
```

Also the Bust property if needed:

```
    private readonly int blackjack = 21;
    public bool Bust
    {
        get { return Bust = Total > blackjack; }
        private set { }
    }
```

Comment: the field `this.total` must be used into the getter otherwise you'll end up recalculating the total as you did actually.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Not the problem; his property is capitalized properly. `total` *is* `this.total`

Comment: If you're recalculating the value to return each time, it doesn't matter what you set `total` to - whatever value it has is overwritten.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET :) Right! I think it was a local variable.

Comment: @Matt Jones ahh I see, but how can I implement that logic but also be able to set it to a different value?

Comment: Is `Player.Bust` a bool?

Comment: @MattJones yes, also a property, but I think that one works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would separate the Total calculation and Bust a bit differently:

```
public class Player
{
    public bool Bust { get; set; }

    public int GetTotal()
    {
        if (Bust)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var total = 0;
        foreach (int card in hand)
        {
            total += card;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

A few things to notice:

- the calculation is done in a method not a property - i think this is a cleaner way since a property is supposed to be quite simple and not have any logic in it
- include Bust in the GetTotal calculation and return 0 if Bust is set to true
- always compute the total value, unless you have a very good reason to have a cached version of it

Hope this helps.

Comment: In that case won't I have to call the GetTotal() method before using total?

Comment: in this case Total property and variable are gone as it's always calculated on the fly. The only way to get the total for a player is to call the GetTotal method.  Makes sense?

Comment: I think that is how I had it originally but I was told on CR that it would be better to turn total into a property. see the link I provided for more details

Comment: Well, in the code you've provided you were using a private variable that you've computed in a method and then return the private variable. Agreed, this doesn't make sense, which is why in my code the "total" private variable is gone altogether. To get my code integrated into yours all you have to do is call the GetTotal method anywhere you need to get the total score.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're recalculating the total everytime you call the getter of your property.

A solution is to make the field `total` as `Nullable<int>` so if it is `null`, you do the logic you're doing actually otherwise return what is set in the field `total`.

```
public class Player
{
    private int? total; // <- Nullable<int> here
    public int Total
    {
        get
        {
            if(total.HasValue) // <- If value is set return that value.
            {
                return total.Value;
            }

            total = 0;
            foreach (int card in hand)
            {
                total += card;
            }

            return total.Value;
        }
        set { this.total = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the data type to `int?` will break the code using the variable directly, for example `return total;` needs to change to `return total.Value;` or the more efficient `return total.GetValueOrDefault();`